# Does a shortcode with a single attribute have to use an array?

Tags: shortcode

I want to build a shortcode that takes a single attribute.

Everything online is telling me to make it using an array:

```
// Add Shortcode
function bg_comparison_points_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'custom_field' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'comparison_points'
    );
    return bg_calculate_points($custom_field);
}
add_shortcode( 'comparison_points', 'bg_comparison_points_shortcode' );
```

But in my mind something like this would be much simpler

```
// Add Shortcode
function bg_comparison_points_shortcode( $custom_field ) {
    return bg_calculate_points($custom_field);
}
add_shortcode( 'comparison_points', 'bg_comparison_points_shortcode' );
```

Is there a problem doing this simpler version?

Comment: if the function "bg_calculate_points" do all the work, you can directly use `add_shortcode( 'comparison_points', 'bg_calculate_points' );`

Comment: @mmm but I need to pass a 'custom_field' attribute to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that it won't work.

The shortcode system doesn't know how many arguments will be passed, so it gives you an array `$atts` that contains the attributes. When it is only one, then the array will only have one element. When no argument is passed, the array will be empty.

Check the [official documentation for a proper example](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/#complete-example):

> ```
> <?php
> function wporg_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '')
> {
>     // normalize attribute keys, lowercase
>     $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);
>
>     // override default attributes with user attributes
>     $wporg_atts = shortcode_atts([
>                                      'title' => 'WordPress.org',
>                                  ], $atts, $tag);
>
>     // [...]
>
>     // return output
>     return $o;
> }
>
> function wporg_shortcodes_init()
> {
>     add_shortcode('wporg', 'wporg_shortcode');
> }
>
> add_action('init', 'wporg_shortcodes_init');
> ```

Longer code doesn't mean the code is worse.

In this case I'd say the opposite is the case: If you use the array and everything how it is intended, then it will be very easy to expand your shortcode in the future, keep working on it and other developers will better understand your code.

Given this, you could write your shortcode like so

```
function bg_comparison_points_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '')
{
    // normalize attribute keys, lowercase
    $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);

    // override default attributes with user attributes
    $comparison_points_atts = shortcode_atts([
                                                 'custom_field' => '',
                                             ], $atts, $tag);

    return bg_calculate_points( $comparison_points_atts['custom_field'] );
}

function bg_comparison_points_init()
{
    add_shortcode('comparison_points', 'bg_comparison_points_shortcode');
}

add_action('init', 'bg_comparison_points_init');
```

Comment: Actually my top shortcode example is not working for me either, and your example seems really confusing to me (sorry, I'm new to all this). Do you know of a simple example I can copy? My shortcode just needs pass the 'custom_field' attribute to the `bg_calculate_points($custom_field)` function

Comment: @TinyTiger Please check my update. You can't use `$custom_field` but need to use `$atts['custom_field']` or in my case `$comparison_points_atts['custom_field']`. Also make sure, `bg_calculate_points()` actually `return`s the output and doesn't just `echo` it