# Shortcode will not pass attribute through to my function

Tags: shortcode

This question is different from [my earlier question about shortcodes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303612/does-a-shortcode-with-a-single-attribute-have-to-use-an-array). Yes they both talk about shortcodes, but they are asking different things and therefore should be separated out. Otherwise all "shortcode" questions on this site would need to be marked as duplicate.

**Original question:**

My shortcode won't pass the attribute through to the function.

Here is the shortcode used inside my post: `[points custom_field="company_location"]`

Here is the function for my shortcode:

```
// Add Shortcode
function points_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'custom_field' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'points'
    );
    return bg_calculate_points ($custom_field);
}
add_shortcode( 'points', 'points_shortcode' );
```

When performing a `var_dump` on my function it shows `NULL` when I was expecting to see the `company_location` string that was passed through by the shortcode attribute.

```
function bg_calculate_points ($field) {
    var_dump($field);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you create a new question ? @kero give you the answer in your other question : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303612/does-a-shortcode-with-a-single-attribute-have-to-use-an-array

Comment: @mmm because the other question was asking something different.

Answer (score 2):

[`shortcode_atts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) returns an array (which is assigned to `$atts` in your code).

It does not create new variables like [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) would - by the way using `extract()` is usually not recommended.

So in your code, `$custom_field` (line 11) is not defined.

The value you are looking for is in `$atts['custom_field']` instead.

Changing line 11 to `return bg_calculate_points( $atts['custom_field'] );` will fix it.